# ADFS problem - Automatic Logon is not working

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, adfs, windows-server-2016, adfs4.0

I have a problem when logging onto an application using ADFS via a web browser (IE or Chrome). I **want to login automatically and transparently a user (current user logged) with ADFS** SAML without entering these identifiers.

So I have 2 servers running Windows 2016 Server:
- the first Serv1: domain controller with Active Directory directory
- the second Serv2: ADFS server (4.0) and it is join to the controller Serv1

when I tried to access to my application, I encounter the following error :

> An error occurred. Contact your administrator for more information
>
> Activity ID: 00000000-0000-0000-d000-0080000000fa Relying party:
>   preprod.xxxxxxxxx.com - DMS Error time: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 13:27:07 GMT
>   Cookie: enabled User agent string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
>   Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.80
>   Safari/537.36

We can see the below in the ADFS event log on ADFS server:

> Encountered error during federation passive request.
>
> Additional Data
>
> Protocol Name:  Saml
>
> Relying Party: 
>   https://preprod.xxxxxxxxx.com:443/auth/saml/metadata/alias/dms
>
> Exception details: 
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.AuthenticationFailedException: MSIS3111: Non
>   domain user is not supported by AD FS. --->
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException:
>   MSIS3111: Non domain user is not supported by AD FS.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.LocalAccountStores.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryCpTrustStore.ProcessPrincipal(IClaimsPrincipal
>   incomingPrincipal)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.BeginGetScope(IClaimsPrincipal
>   principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService.BeginIssue(IClaimsPrincipal
>   principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>   request, IList`1& identityClaimSet, List`1 additionalClaims)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken
>   request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken
>   request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(MSISRequestSecurityToken
>   signInRequest, Uri& replyTo, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.RequestSingleSignOnToken(ProtocolContext
>   context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken
>   deviceSecurityToken)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSsoSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext
>   context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken
>   deviceSecurityToken, SecurityToken& ssoSecurityToken)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext
>   context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken
>   deviceSecurityToken)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext
>   protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext
>   context)
>
> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException:
>   MSIS3111: Non domain user is not supported by AD FS.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.LocalAccountStores.ActiveDirectory.ActiveDirectoryCpTrustStore.ProcessPrincipal(IClaimsPrincipal
>   incomingPrincipal)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SecurityTokenService.MSISSecurityTokenService.BeginGetScope(IClaimsPrincipal
>   principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.SecurityTokenService.BeginIssue(IClaimsPrincipal
>   principal, RequestSecurityToken request, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.WSTrust.SecurityTokenServiceManager.Issue(RequestSecurityToken
>   request, IList`1& identityClaimSet, List`1 additionalClaims)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.PassiveProtocolHandler.SubmitRequest(MSISRequestSecurityToken
>   request, IList`1& identityClaimCollection)

In the other machine, i have this error :

https://srv-adfs.ppppppppp.local/adfs/ls/wia?SAMLRequest=jZJBb4JAEIXv%2FRVk77CAaHQjGFtjamJTIthDb8OyIhV26c5i%2BvOLotFeTJO57GTmm5f3djr7qSvrKDSWSobEc1xiCclVXsoiJNt0aY%2FJLHqaItSV37B5a%2FZyI75bgcaaIwptur0XJbGthU6EPpZcbDfrkOyNaZBR2mjRaJU7SuW6PAqHq5oFwYBCR6InKk2SdwpVCUjzGom16NClBHPWc6WgPtrZobEh36GTAT%2B0TaFV2zjIeU1PXVohJdZSaS7OIkOygwoFsVaLkMA%2By3aDcTH0vvKxnweBPxZ8UnDu8WGWdTMYA2In77aF2IqVRAPShMR3vYntjmzPTb2AdeX7zmjgfRIr1soorqrnUvaWtVoyBVgik1ALZIazZP62Zr7jsqwfQvaaprEdvycpsT6u1vsn67swJLLe7Mes5nKYRH027KxY3xMeA%2BCaHon%2Bn1UtDORg4BbYlN6fjy7Pvz8l%2BgU%3D&RelayState=%7C%7Cbackup-webclient&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2F04%2Fxmldsig-more%23rsa-sha256&Signature=SxWuSQC3I77BXcfCxR%2Bicp1ES%2FgrQDZdx8W8XPxC51JRmNeVxfXI%2BDWgCV8bMrTl%2BYc8I6VZPJxDVPPzTQEZihQaXl0ib2Q268OiNwU1bN9pDL6EpuMM9nCxuEQEdtW58M%2F%2Bjs07j1Rp40VD8AVbvQrpv67AgXXdLWGrSSvZHPwrHLy8fhpSDmg57F8g1zD5%2BMpijrx%2F4n5e8MIK6fBUDPWfAaWCjXgHoo%2B7PFr%2Fp8w5MMa9ZPLDg7yQrMGSQ3on1UxpM091Uu85S%2ByI0aYDHmgZk%2BmGwBUblDWleenUwyAMjopZ3TJx4%2Feng2uBD8%2FbLfWUmbitMMMdsLbIOEb%2Bng%3D%3D&client-request-id=00000000-0000-0000-1201-0080000000dc

> HTTP 400 BadRequest The webpage cannot be found

Do you have an idea about this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting an SPN (Service Principal Name) to the ADFS service account
HTTP/FQDN